# How do I get my HTML5 project in Netbeans to recognize PHP?

Tags: php, netbeans

I have created a web page in `NetBeans` with `Html 5` and `CSS`, and now I want to add a `PHP` file in that project, but there is no option to add a php file.

I added empty file (`xxxxx.file`) and renamed it `xxxxx.php` and added the php code there, but it doesn't recognize it as `php` code. It sees the file as `php` file.

What should I do? Should I create new `PHP` project and copy the `html` and `css` files from my old project to the `php` project to get them working all together?

Comment: Change your file name inside actual directory, not in NetBeans. Also try switching to `php` project or creating new `php` project with existing sources.

Comment: What do you mean that it doesnt recognize it as php code? The php isnt syntax highlighted?

Answer (score 0):

You can have `php` files in HTML5 projects. If you are not seeing the syntax highlighting for the code make sure that your `php` files have the opening php tag:

```
<?php
```

Without this the exitor will not highlight it correctly

Answer (score 0):

if PHP's aren't being recognised you should install the PHP plugin for Netbeans. You should go to Tools > Plugins > Available Plugins and select the ones for PHP in the list. Then, restart the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a Netbeans bug which makes you impossible to add php files to html5 projects. The answer, as given by Netbeans people, is to create a new php project and add the html5 files there.

Here you can see the bug report on netbeans forum: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=226280